# Powershell script to check Windows Event Logs for Critical messages

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell script that checks in the Application and System Windows Event logs for Errors. Is there away to also let it check for Critical messages? in the Windows Event Logs. Below is a sample script:

```
Set-Variable -Name EventAgeDays -Value 1     #we will take events for the latest 7 days
Set-Variable -Name CompArr -Value @("Server 1")   # replace it with your server names
Set-Variable -Name LogNames -Value @("Application", "System")  # Checking app and system logs
Set-Variable -Name EventTypes -Value @("Error")  # Loading only Errors and Warnings
Set-Variable -Name ExportFolder -Value "C:\EventLogs\"


$el_c = @()   #consolidated error log
$now=get-date
$startdate=$now.adddays(-$EventAgeDays)
$ExportFile=$ExportFolder + "el" + $now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd---hh-mm-ss") + ".csv"  # we cannot use standard delimiteds like ":"

foreach($comp in $CompArr)
{
  foreach($log in $LogNames)
  {
    Write-Host Processing $comp\$log
    $el = get-eventlog -ComputerName $comp -log $log -After $startdate -EntryType $EventTypes
    $el_c += $el  #consolidating
  }
}
$el_sorted = $el_c | Sort-Object TimeGenerated    #sort by time
Write-Host Exporting to $ExportFile
$el_sorted|Select EntryType, TimeGenerated, Source, EventID, MachineName, Message | Export-CSV $ExportFile -NoTypeInfo  #EXPORT
Write-Host Done!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Set-Variable -Name EventAgeDays -Value 1     #we will take events for the latest 7 days
    Set-Variable -Name CompArr -Value @("localhost")   # replace it with your server names
    Set-Variable -Name LogNames -Value @("Application", "System")  # Checking app and system logs
    Set-Variable -Name EventTypes -Value @("1")  # Loading only Errors and Warnings
    Set-Variable -Name ExportFolder -Value "C:\EventLogs\"


    $el_c = @()   #consolidated error log
    $now=get-date
    $startdate=$now.adddays(-$EventAgeDays)
    $ExportFile=$ExportFolder + "el" + $now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd---hh-mm-ss") + ".csv"  # we cannot use standard delimiteds like ":"

    foreach($comp in $CompArr)
    {
      foreach($log in $LogNames)
      {
        Write-Host Processing $comp\$log
        $el = get-winevent -ComputerName $comp -FilterHashtable @{logname="$log";level=$eventtypes;starttime=$startdate}
        $el_c += $el  #consolidating
      }
    }
    $el_sorted = $el_c | Sort-Object TimeGenerated    #sort by time
    #Write-Host Exporting to $ExportFile
    $el_sorted|Select LevelDisplayName, TimeCreated, ProviderName, ID, MachineName, Message
```

You can change "eventtypes" to 1,2,3,4 (critical,error,warning,information)

Comment: Hi Paul, After putting the script together, everything works and produces the output with the information i need but when i schedule the powershell script with task scheduler, it runs and completes successfully but the output is empty. What could i be doing wrong here?

Comment: Please set the PS execution policy **Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -force **

Comment: How do I set this in the task scheduler? The server that I am running the script on has the execution policy set to RemoteSigned. When I run the script manually with the powershell ISE or CLI, it works fine and produces the required output but when I schedule it with task scheduler the output file is produced but it is empty

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter critical events then you need to use `get-winevent` instead of `get-eventlog`

something like this

```
Get-WinEvent -computername $comparr -FilterHashTable @{logname=$lognames; Level=1}
```

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2009/05/21/processing-event-logs-in-powershell/
https://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh849682.aspx

Answer (score 0):

$CritSysMsgs = Get-WinEvent -LogName "System" | Where-Object -FilterScript {$_.LevelDisplayName -eq "Critical"}
Write-Host  "Critaical messages: $CritSysMsgs"

Comment: give us more supporting information how it answer the question, please